# jOOQ - How to create a SQL query with WHERE having multiple conditions

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I want to create a query which should work like this one:

```
SELECT 
  sensor_id,
  measurement_time,
  measurement_value
FROM 
  public.measurement_pm2_5
WHERE
  (sensor_id = 1 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(123) AND to_timestamp(100000))
  OR (sensor_id = 1 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(500000) AND to_timestamp(99999999999))
  OR (sensor_id = 49 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(555) AND to_timestamp(556))
  OR (sensor_id = 9 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(7654) AND to_timestamp(999999299347))
  OR (sensor_id = 44 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(4252) AND to_timestamp(999949999348))
  OR (sensor_id = 60 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(63452) AND to_timestamp(999998999349))
  ;
```

**The number of `OR`s in this query may vary.**

Is it even possible to build such a query using jOOQ with its type safe API or I have to create it manually using plain SQL?

I know that if there wouldn't be additional statement about `measurement_time` - different for every `sensor_id` - it would look like this:

```
Set<Integer> sensorIds = new HashSet<>();
sensorIds.add(1);
sensorIds.add(49);
sensorIds.add(9);
sensorIds.add(44);
sensorIds.add(60);
Timestamp startTime = new Timestamp(123L);
Timestamp endTime = new Timestamp(999999999999L);
try(java.sql.Connection conn = Connection.hikariDataSource.getConnection()) {
    System.out.println("SQL = " + DSL.using(conn).select()
        .from(MEASUREMENT_PM2_5)
        .where(MEASUREMENT_PM2_5.SENSOR_ID.in(sensorIds))
        .and(MEASUREMENT_PM2_5.MEASUREMENT_TIME.between(startTime, endTime))
        .getSQL());
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But unfortunately I have different timestamps for different `sensor_id`s.

```
private class TimeRange {
    Timestamp startTime;
    Timestamp endTime;

    Timestamp getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    Timestamp getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
}
...
Map<Integer, List<TimeRange>> sensorIDsWithTimeRange
```

Comment: The parameter to `and()` and `or()` can be a `Collection` of `Condition`s.  Can you build the Collection on the fly to pass to DSL?

Comment: Should the `Collection` of `Condition`s be in `where()`?

Comment: It looks like `Collection` is putting `AND` between `Condition`s.

Comment: Do note that from a performance perspective, it's probably a good idea not to have an `OR` predicate at the "top level" of your `WHERE` clause. Instead, write `sensor_id IN (1, 9, 44, 49, 60) AND (... OR ... OR ...)`, which helps at least use an index on the `sensor_id` column

Comment: But different time ranges are assigned to different `sensor_id`s. If I use `sensor_id IN (1, 9, 44, 49, 60) AND (... OR ... OR ...)` it won't be the query I want because I would get data from every time range from every `sensor_id` that is in the query, right? But anyway, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I need some kind of `Collection` that is putting `OR`s between `Condition`s instead of `AND`s. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly doable with JooQ.

You want to create a suitable [`Condition`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html) and plug it into your query.

The question is how to build a condition... And there are many ways to build one.

For instance:

```
final Condition c1 = someField.eq(someOtherField);
// or
final Condition c1 = someField.lessThan(someValue);
```

The way to obtain a `Field` reference depend on your setup.

Possibilites are endless; and then if you have two conditions c1 and c2, to build a condition c, you can:

```
final Condition c = c1.and(c2); // or c1.or(c2)
```

and plug that condition c into your final query.

If you use JooQ, chances are that you have generated the metadata code already, and if not, even with only the JDBC URL alone, JooQ can infer table and column names for you.